# Android, long click, or long pressed click on views?

Tags: android, view, click

Hey androids and cyborgs, i would like to ask if there is an alternative to the traditional and the normally used onClick() event. I would like to use a something with a long delay before the specific listview-item's function to execute,

in short, i want a onLONGCLICK() event!

root of the problem, i would like my listview to be scrollable without accidentally clicking an item within the said listview, no immediate pop-ups/dialogs, no annoyances. thanks, I hope you can help me with my endeavors... :D

thanks, for help...

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {                        
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {                                                        
                        Intent intent = new Intent(AddNewImmunizationActivity.this, AddNewImmuDialogActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("requestCode", IMMU_DIALOG_EDIT);
                        intent.putExtra("listPosition", position);
                        intent.putExtra("availableVaccines", processAvailableVaccines());
                        intent.putExtra("vaccine", listItem.getVaccine());
                        intent.putExtra("year", listItem.getYear());
                        intent.putExtra("month", listItem.getMonth());
                        intent.putExtra("day", listItem.getDay());
                        intent.putExtra("adverseReaction", listItem.getAdverseReaction());
                        intent.putExtra("doctor", listItem.getDoctor());
                        startActivityForResult(intent, IMMU_DIALOG_EDIT);   
                        return true;
                    }                   
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey! The onLongClick event is there since API Level 1! Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html).